# How to find a abstract class instance and call an instance method based on the instance' attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, instance, abstract-class

I want to call an instance method but the instance itself is unknown to me. The instance can be identified by it's attributes which I know, e.g. a unique name.

Here're my class definitions and instantiation:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class MyAbstractClass():
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.name)

class MyFirstClass(MyAbstractClass):
   def __init__(self):
       self.name = 'first'  

class MySecondClass(MyAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'second' 

my_first_class_instance = MyFirstClass()
my_second_class_instance = MySecondClass()
```

What I want to achive is a look-up by name:

```
def myPrint('first'):
    # should call my_first_class_instance.do_something()

def myPrint('second'):
    # should call my_second_class_instance.do_something()
```

I looked into the built-in class methods but didn't find a way to manage the parametrization of the calls.
What's a good way of doing this?

Comment: So you want to *lookup* by `name`?

Comment: I don't think your current setup is moving in the right direction at all. Why is the base class abstract? Why are you making two nearly identical subclasses instead of two instances? Why not store a dictionary mapping name to instance?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes look up by name - re edited

Comment: @jonrsharpe the base class is abstract because I want to implement a couple of methods which' functionality vary with the subclasses

Comment: That doesn't *require* an abstract base class. How will the behaviour vary? Do you intend to have multiple instances of each subclass? How should it decide which to call? As it stands it seems like `{'first': MyFirstClass(), 'second': MySecondClass()}` would suffice, but it's hard to say without more context.

Comment: note that the [syntax for metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) has changed in python 3.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to work with abstract classes, because I want to force that a number of methods are implemented in the subclasses. There will be many methods in the Abstract Class level that have to implemented on a child level

Comment: A `name` attribute only exists in _instances_ of your two classes—it's not a class attribute. So if you wanted to lookup instances by its value, you would need to keep track of all instances that are created, something which would be problematic...